# Using awk to get the percentile of lines in a file

Tags: unix, awk, statistics, percentile

I a having a sorted file with numeric values like

```
foo 2.3
bar 2.6
baz 4.7
```

and would like to have a one-liner which puts the percentile of a line into the last column, like

```
foo 2.3 0.3333
bar 2.6 0.6666
baz 4.7 1.0000
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean percent of lines, for this you need to know the number of lines first.

Here's one way to do it as a two-pass solution with awk:

```
 awk 'FNR == NR { tot=NR; next } { printf( "%s %.4f\n", $0, FNR/tot) }' file file
```

Output:

```
foo 2.3 0.3333
bar 2.6 0.6667
baz 4.7 1.0000
```

The first block is only active during `FNR == NR` i.e. the first pass. The second block takes care of the printing.

#### Other alternatives to determine length of file

Use `NR-1` when starting second pass (`FNR != NR`):

```
awk 'FNR != NR { if(!tot) tot=NR-1; printf( "%s %.4f\n", $0, FNR/tot) }' file file
```

Use `wc` before running awk:

```
awk -v tot=$(wc -l < file) '{ printf( "%s %.4f\n", $0, FNR/tot) }' file
```

Comment: Thank you. It generally does the job, but `percent of lines` is outputted to the first column without a delimiting space.

Comment: @MarioKonschake: it works with gawk and nawk, which version of awk are you using?

Comment: Run the command dos2unix on your file. looks like it contains ^M characters

Comment: Good catch Guru. @MarioKonschake, `^M` is carriage return, the same as `\r`. An alternative to changing the file is to set the record separator to `\r\n`, e.g. `awk -v RS='\r\n' ...`.

Comment: What about if the files are Huge and proceessing the file once itself takes more time?

Comment: @sarathi Then this is the correct approach since you wouldn't be able to store that much data in an array.

Comment: @Thor - setting the RS to more than one character would make your script gawk-specific. Might be OK but worth giving the OP a heads up.

Comment: +1 for the approach but you can replace `FNR == NR { tot=NR; next }` or similar with just `tot=NR-FNR` in any script where you just want to process the file on the second pass with a count of the number of lines in the file.

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes `RS=pattern` is not portable, but it is supported by at least gawk and mawk.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'c=NR-FNR{printf "%s %.4f\n",$0,FNR/c}' file file
foo 2.3 0.3333
bar 2.6 0.6667
baz 4.7 1.0000
```

Answer (score 1):

even though @thor solution is good, there is no need to traverse the file twice.Instead we can do it inside the memory itself.

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0;}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i],i/NR;}' your_file
```

tested:

```
> cat temp
foo 2.3
bar 2.6
baz 4.7
> awk '{a[NR]=$0;}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i],i/NR;}' temp
foo 2.3 0.333333
bar 2.6 0.666667
baz 4.7 1
```

if you are specific about the precision then use below:

```
> awk '{a[NR]=$0;}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)printf("%s %0.4f\n",a[i],i/NR);}' temp
foo 2.3 0.3333
bar 2.6 0.6667
baz 4.7 1.0000
```